# javascript pass element from one function to another

Tags: javascript

this is a partial code:

```
function readXmlUsingXPath(i,guid, xpath) {
    var xmlDoc = loadXML("gameFeed.aspx?guid=" + guid);
    if (xmlDoc == null) { document.getElementById(guid).innerHTML = "UPDATING"; return }
    else { };
    i.innerHTML = xmlDoc.selectNodes(xpath)[0].text;
}

window.onload = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('jackpot').length; i++) {
        var guid = document.getElementsByTagName('jackpot')[i].getAttribute('data-g').split('|')[0];
        var xpath = document.getElementsByTagName('jackpot')[i].getAttribute('data-g').split('|')[1];
        readXmlUsingXPath(document.getElementsByTagName('jackpot')[i],guid, xpath);
    }
}
```

basicly, what i want to do is pass the element from the onload function, to the readXmlUsingXpath function, so i could change it.
but i get an unknown runtime error...

as asked, some sample html:

```
<li>
<a href="/gamepath/"><span>gameTitle</span>
<span><jackpot data-g="<%=game.Guid %>|<%=game.GamingProperties.JackpotFeedXpath %>">UPDATING . . .</jackpot></span>
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Please, no suggestions about jquery.

Comment: Could you please show a sample of the HTML you're selecting? Also, you should cache the result of the `getElementsByTagName()` call *outside* the `for` loop. Repeated DOM selection like that is very expensive.

Comment: what/where is your error?  your code looks fine on quick inspection.

Comment: ...and I'm pretty sure @Anurag was just messing with you a bit. :o)

Comment: lol, its ok, im sick and tierd, and hardly can finish my work...
the error is on i.innerHTML line, and the error is "Unknown runtime error".

Comment: Please disregard the validity of the html.

Comment: can you provide some rendered output rather than the sample with the raw code blocks? which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so i modified the code a bit,
and made it simpler.

now it works as its supposed to.

```
function loadXMLDoc(guid,xpath,i) {

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();}
    else {xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
    xmlhttp.async = true;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            i.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseXML.selectNodes(xpath)[0].text;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "gameFeed.aspx?guid=" + guid, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("pre");
for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    var data = tags[i].getAttribute('data-g').split('|'), guid = data[0], xpath = data[1];
    loadXMLDoc(guid,xpath,tags[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, yes - cache the results of `getElementsByTagName()` and `.getAttribute('data-g').split('|')` into a variable:

```
var myDataG = MyJackpotElement.getAttribute('data-g').split('|');
```

Then instead of processing XPath that comes from your HTML source code, since you pass the `guid` to a server side script anyway, make the server script process the item (with XPath) on the server side - so it would get the xpath expression from the item you're loading by Guid :)

Make the server side script return you **the value you're looking for** (`gameFeed.aspx?guid=`), not the XML that you will further process on the client side to find the value.

Comment: i cannot make the server script do that,
since each request is going to some other server,
asking for all those values will take time,
while i prefer to show the user some "action" while he waits.
doing it one by one, i can update the status.

Comment: and about caching etc, i still work on this code,
its just a sample breakdown, luckily you guyz dont also recommend to change variable names etc....
i just asked a simple question... :(

Answer (score 0):

Does the code work after refactoring it as per Denis’s suggestions?

One big problem with the way you kept performing a getElementsByTagName, even aside from the huge performance hit, is that if the collection changes for any reason, the length might not be correct anymore, and you could be requesting element 9 where only 8 exist.

Also, it’s possible that changing the `innerHTML` of an element will throw the browser off.

Side nit: I’ve renamed the `i` parameter of the `readXmlUsingXPath` function to `jackpot`, which seems a little more appropriate than just `i`.

```
function readXmlUsingXPath(jackpot, guid, xpath) {
    var xmlDoc = loadXML("gameFeed.aspx?guid=" + guid);
    if (xmlDoc == null) {
        document.getElementById(guid).innerHTML = "UPDATING"; 
        return;
    }
    var firstNode = xmlDoc.selectNodes(xpath).item(0);
    jackpot.innerHTML = firstNode.text;
}

window.onload = function () {
    var jackpots = document.getElementsByTagName('jackpot');
    for (var i = 0; i < jackpots.length; i++) {
        var data = jackpots[i].getAttribute('data-g').split('|'),
        guid = data[0],
        xpath = data[1];
        readXmlUsingXPath(jackpots[i], guid, xpath);
    }
}
```

Comment: The object returned by `getElementsByTagName` is live, so even if document changes occur during iteration, they will automatically reflect in the `jackpots` object. See this [snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/uqahJ/) for an example.

Comment: @Anurag is right about the live list, although that wouldn't even matter in the code in the question since OP is making a separate request *just* to get the `length`. So if all of a sudden all the `jackpot` elements disappeared, `i` would no longer be less than the `length`, and you wouldn't enter the block for the `for` loop. The way it would break would be if you cached the `length` before the loop, then the number of `jackpot` elements changed.

Comment: thank you guyz, but since i dont find a solution to this, i will try a diffrent approache.
i will update this thread as soon as i find one.
@martijn - just a q, why did you change the two variables (guid,xpath) into one array ?

Comment: @RephaelHerjcovici: I didn’t change `guid,xpath` into one array: the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)() function does that in your code already.  But instead of calling the `split` function twice, and getting a different element each time, it’s more efficient to call the split function once, caching the result, and using the different elements separately.

Comment: @RephaelHerjcovici: I just wondered: are you sure the problem lies in the `innerHTML` assignment?  Couldn’t it be that there’s a problem with the XPath query?  I’ve adjusted my answer to separate the XPath execution and the innerHTML assignment.  Could you try this, and see where exactly the error occurs now?

Comment: @martinjn, the error still accures on "jackpot.innerHTML = firstNode.text;" 
thx for the split function tip btw.
i also tried manually entering the xpath, while i do know the exact location, but still, with no success.
i also just notices that i am using ASync=false, which is not what i intended.